# Italic/slanted math font and kerning

Tags: math-mode, subscripts, kerning, italic-correction

I'd like to write a macro for typesetting slanted letters in bold for highlighting vectors. I've used this implemenation:

```
\newcommand\vect[1]{\text{\bfseries\sffamily\slshape#1\/}}
```

But I've run into problems with kerning -- when I want subscripted vector (like `\vect{F}_g`), the italic correction (`\/`) causes there's to wide space but when I omit `\/`, the space between vector and `|` is too narrow.

It's the same when I tried it with `\mathit` macro. So I wonder whether there is any possibility how to handle this in general (not to have `\/` written after each vector without subscript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your default sans serif font family should have a boldface slanted variant (this is the case with Latin Modern)

```
\usepackage{lmodern}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\vect}{OT1}{\sfdefault}{bx}{sl}
```

Now `$\vect{F}_{g}$` will not suffer from the problem.

It's not necessary to use Latin Modern fonts throughout; if you use the standard Computer Modern fonts, the declaration

```
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\vect}{OT1}{lmss}{bx}{sl}
```

will do.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know whether you did this because you like to tinker with `(La)TeX` and wanted a challege, and maybe my answer is marginal, but for completeness I guess I should mention it. There are packages to do exactly this: italic boldface math fonts to denote vectors the ISO way: [`bm`](http://ctan.org/pkg/bm), [`isomath`](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/isomath) or [`maybemath`](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/maybemath). The documentation and a peek at the code should give insight into how kerning (and other stuff) has been handled.